# Grab value of div and parse to interger for calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsing

I have a javascript function that does some calculations. At the end of the function it stores the value in

```
$('#n3').html(n3);
$('#n4').html(n4);
$('#n5').html(n5);
$('#n6').html(n6);
$('#n7').html(n7);
```

Then i display them in a div like this

```
<div id="n3"></div>
<div id="n4"></div>
<div id="n5"></div>
<div id="n6"></div>
<div id="n7"></div>
```

That all works fine. Then i want to grab the id of the divs, and then parse them so i can use the interger.

```
 var val3 = $('#n3').val();
   var val4 = $('#n4').val();
   var val5 = $('#n5').val();
   var val6 = $('#n6').val();
   var val7 = $('#n7').val();
   var newVal3 = parseFloat(val3);
   var newVal4 = parseFloat(val4);
   var newVal5 = parseFloat(val5);
   var newVal6 = parseFloat(val6);
   var newVal7 = parseFloat(val7);
```

So i tried to just store them in a var and parse but this is not working. I am trying to use the data for display in a google chart.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: divs do not have values. Are you trying to read the text you set?

Comment: can probably simplify this into a loop...what is the data structure needed? Alos what is original source of `n3,n4..`   can't you use the values you already have without parsing text?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call `val()` it tries to read the `value` of the element. This only works for form elements (for example text input).

If you want to **get the div's text content as a number**, you can do it like this:

```
var div = $('#n5');
var number = parseFloat(div.text());
```

That will give you the text contents inside the div and parse them with `parseFloat`.

If you want to **find the first number inside the div** even though there's other content, you can use regular expressions (but be warned that they're not fool-proof, you need to ensure you have predictable content in your div):

```
var divText = $('#n5').text();
var match = divText.match(/\d+(\.\d+)?/);       // Only matches integers and floats.
var number = match ? parseFloat(match[0]) : 0;  // 0 because we didn't find a match.
```

Note that the regular expression above doesn't match formatted numbers (e.g., `1,234.56` or `1.123456e+10`)

Comment: Lets say that after my calculation function $('#n3').html(n3); equalls 83762. Then the div <div id="n3"></div> is displaying that number on the screen. I want that number not the id.

Comment: @user4742637 Ok I updated the answer to exclude the `id` solution. Do you get NaN when using the `parseFloat(div.text())` solution? If yes, could you try outputting the text content to the console by doing something like this in your code: `console.log($('#n3').text())` and checking the developer console in your browser?

Comment: the google chart says it can't be a string. So i don't know if the number is not parsing or if it isn't a number to start with.

Comment: The "value" or the text in the divs will always be a number so the content is predictable.

Comment: Ok, if i put numbers directly in the div such as <div id="n3">45345</div> then the thing works. So is it possible that it is trying to get and parse data that doen't yet exist. If so, how can i make sure the divs are populated after the function is run before the data gets pulled form them?

Comment: If you know how/when the data is being populated you can trigger an event which will get the value out of the element. If you don't know, then you can either look into DOM mutation (advanced) or go with the simple solution and try `setTimeout(callback, ms)` which will call the function `callback` after `ms` milliseconds.

Answer (score 1):

You want to use `.text()` or `.html()` rather than `.val()` on non-input elements.

Comment: .text and .html give me a NaN.

Comment: I changed the values above to var val3 = $('#n3').text();

Comment: Is there any content in the divs? If so then you'll need to run the variable through the parseFloat - NaN means "not a number", as in, it's text.

Comment: Your use case is a little unclear - I think Blixt's answer explains your options for different use cases pretty well

Answer (score 0):

`div` doesn't have `val`. Use `.html();` or `.text();` to retrieve the value.